# Automatically updating RSS Feed to database

Tags: php, rss

I am looking for code of RSS feed which automatically updates to database.Suppose that even if the admin of the website does not log into his system for one or 2 days ,it needs to be updated and able to view.how can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a cronjob! - If you have your own server check google for informations how to do it depending on your configuration.

Otherwhise there are a few free cronjob providers just google for cronjob.

You set a time when it's executed and an interval - a bot triggers then a file on your webserver. Of course the file on your webserver should be coded to do the job without login and such.

So a simple php file which fits your purpose will do.

Comment: how to setup cronjob on windows system(xp/vista/7) .And is there any difference btwn cronjob in linux and windows?

Comment: There are differences in the setup, but in fact the result stays the same - you just have to open a file periodicaly.

For your reference this could help you on a very new Windows 8 system http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx

And for Windows XP, Vista, 7 this installation guide should to the trick for you: http://drupal.org/node/31506